# sending dictionary parameter with jmeter to rest service

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, jmeter

First of all i am a newbie at jmeter. I searched a lot of documents but unfortunately i did not find to answer for my problem. I have a web api rest service with following sign. I can't send dictionary format parameter.

```
[HttpPost,ActionName("DummyService")]
public Dictionary<string,string> DummyService([FromBody] Dictionary<string,string> parameters)
```

I used Parameters section and BodyData section but parameters are always null.

[image]

How can i achieve that?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to pass some form of a [JSON Array](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) to your web service, in order to do it:

1. Switch to `Body Data` tab
2. Put your JSON payload there like:

   ```
   {
     "Parameters": [
       {
         "Key": "Key1",
         "Value": "Value1"
       },
       {
         "Key": "Key2",
         "Value": "value2"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Most likely you will need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your test plan and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) header with the value of `application/json`
4. (optional) Consider upgrading to JMeter 3.0, looking into screenshot it seems you're sitting on an older version

   [image: JSON Dictionary]

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for more information on setting up JMeter for API testing

Comment: I did what you said but it did not work. After i changed the json parameter it works. Final json parameter                                                {
      "Key1": "Value1",
      "Key2": "Value2"
}  Thank you.